# Di box for bass amp

Tags: mixer

I am using a Berrenger bass amp with a "di out" connection and running it to a house mixing board for the PA system,the speaker output is run to a monitor on stage.  Should I use a di box between the amp and the house mixer?  Thanks for your reply

Comment: Usually, "DI out" means that the amp basically has the equivalent of a DI box built in, so you can run straight from the DI out to the mixer (so the answer would be *no, you should not use a DI box*.) Just to be clear, what's the model no of the amp?

Comment: If it's an XLR socket, it will be direct to the p.a./mixer

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't have to use a DI Box as your amp already has some kind of DI in it. So you can basically run that directly into the desk without any problems